# Rails storing datetimes differently than expected; affecting queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm storing DateTimes in an SQLite database. I have set the time zone in the Rails configuration. The dates are displaying correctly, but are being stored as a completely different number. I assume it's being stored with a timezone agnostic date, as UTC or something like that. However, this is affecting the returned results when I query by date.

```
day = DateTime.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i)
where(start: (day.to_time...day.end_of_day.to_time)).order(:start)
```

The date probably needs to be converted to the same timezone that is stored in the database.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: mysql rather than sqlite but could be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436942/preserving-timezones-in-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Time.zone` can fix a lot of time zone issues when storing and displaying dates & times.

That being said, there is a `change` method in the DateTime class that you can manually set the time zone for an object

I've found these [two](http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails) [articles](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/) especially helpful

Comment: Thanks, those articles really helped. tl;dr: `Time.zone.parse('2013-01-30')`